# How to convert pdf to bmp images in c# winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

How to convert pdf to bmp image in c# windows forms and is there any open source library for conversion of pdf to images.....

Comment: This question might be useful to you:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7864196/pdf-to-image-issues

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this: 
http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php

Or maybe GhostScript:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32274/How-To-Convert-PDF-to-Image-Using-Ghostscript-API

Haven't tested it myself yet, but according to some people it may be the thing you want.